# Redirect to ReactNative component from webview

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using react native WebView to open some complex form steps. I want app user to redirect Android app Home page(react native component) after completing last step(http://example.com/completed/) in WebView.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've solved that problem doing this:

```js
_onLoad(state) {
    //I check the url to see if everything goes right
    if (state.url.indexOf(BASEURL + '/auth/success') != -1) {
      let token = state.url.split("token=")[1];
      token = token.substring(0, token.length - 4);
      //Here I'm caming back
      NavigationsActions.back();
      //In your case you might do something like this:
      NavigationsActions.replaceRoute({
          id: 'your route id'
      });
      SessionActions.setSession(token);
    }
}
```

I've found a great tutorial, which helps me to understand how it works [here](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/05/25/send-receive-data-between-react-native-and-webview.html).

Here you have how my entire component looks like:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  WebView,
  Text
} from 'react-native';
import NavigationsActions from '../../actions/NavigationsActions';
import NavigationConstants from '../../constants/NavigationConstants';
import RouteConstants from '../../constants/RouteConstants';
import SessionActions from '../../actions/SessionActions';

var BASEURL = 'http://localhost:8080';

class FacebookLogIn extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <WebView onNavigationStateChange={this._onLoad} style={styles.container} source={{ uri: BASEURL + '/auth/facebook' }}/>
    );
  }

  _onLoad(state) {
    console.log(state.url);
    if (state.url.indexOf(BASEURL + '/auth/success') != -1) {
      let token = state.url.split("token=")[1];
      token = token.substring(0, token.length - 4);
      NavigationsActions.back();
      SessionActions.setSession(token);
    }
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  }
});

module.exports = FacebookLogIn;
```

Answer (score 2):

I achieve the same to navigate to another component from webview by following the documentation of react-navigation using following link 
[https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-actions.html](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-actions.html)

> for webview inside onNavigationStateChange call 1st one

**1st way**

```
import { StackActions, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Profile' })],
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

**2nd way**
If you have a stack for profile then you can also go through like this check following link [nested react navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-actions.html)

```js
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
  routeName: 'Profile',

  params: {},

  action: NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'SubProfileRoute' }),
});

this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction);
```